# Buscar y pintar texto de una pagina como Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, algoritmos

Tengo el siguiente código que realiza la búsqueda de palabras en un sector de mi pagina, una vez encontrado la palabra pinta toda su etiqueta `a` de color verde:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#buscar_unidad").keyup(function(){
            var texto=$("#buscar_unidad").val().toUpperCase();
            if(texto.length!==0){
                $("#nu0").children("li").each(function(i,e){
                    ul=$(e).children("ul");
                    ul.children("li").each(function(ii,ee){
                        var search=$(ee).children("a").html().toUpperCase();
                        var resultado=search.indexOf(texto);
                        if(texto.length>1 && resultado !== -1){
                            $(ee).children("a").css("color","#00ff00");
                        }else{
                            $(ee).children("a").css("color","");
                        }
                        
                    });
                    
                });  
            }else{
                $("#nu0").children("li").each(function(i,e){
                    ul=$(e).children("ul");
                    ul.children("li").each(function(ii,ee){
                        $(ee).children("a").css("color","");
                    });
                    
                });
            }
            
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="buscar">Buscar</label> <input id="buscar_unidad" type="text">
<ul id="nu0">
    <li>
        Distrito
        <ul id="nu1">
            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/2">DIRECCION EJECUTIVA</a>
                <ul id="nu2">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/3">UNIDAD DE MANTENIMIENTO Y  COORDINACION</a>
                <ul id="nu3">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/4">UNIDAD DE SEGUIMIENTO  A PROYECTOS</a>
                <ul id="nu4">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/5">UNIDAD DE ESTUDIOS Y ELABORACION  DE PROYECTOS</a>
                <ul id="nu5">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/8">UNIDAD  ADMINISTRATIVA Y FINANCIERA</a>
                <ul id="nu8">
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li1">
                <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="1" style="color: red">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        Maestranza
        <ul id="nu6">
            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/7">UNIDAD DE MANTENIMIENTO  DE EQUIPOS</a>
                <ul id="nu7">
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li6">
                <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="6" style="color: red">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        RESIDENCIA ACASIO
        <ul id="nu9">
            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/15">RESIDENCIA ACASIO</a>
                <ul id="nu15">
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li9">
                <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="9" style="color: red">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Todo funciona bien, pero el caso es que quisiera saber:

> como colocar un marcador de donde se encuentra la palabra en el scroll, como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en lo posible solo pintar la parte que esta escrita en el buscador, esto en el scroll de mi sección de búsqueda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

te tengo una solución posible, tiene sus cosillas por mejorar pero la idea principal está. La cosa es que no puedes sobreponer elementos sobre el scroll del body, así que tienes que hacer sobre el scroll de otros elementos, en este caso un elemento auxiliar y a este le tienes que poner un envoltorio que tenga posición relativa para que así con posición absoluta puedas sobreponer los marcadores. Acá una implementación que hice, combiné un poco de Javascript con jQuery.

```js
    function getScrollBarWidth() {
  var inner = document.createElement('p');
  inner.style.width = "100%";
  inner.style.height = "200px";

  var outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.position = "absolute";
  outer.style.top = "0px";
  outer.style.left = "0px";
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  outer.style.width = "200px";
  outer.style.height = "150px";
  outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
  outer.appendChild(inner);

  document.body.appendChild(outer);
  var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
  var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
  if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

  document.body.removeChild(outer);

  return (w1 - w2);
};

let searchHelpers = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#buscar_unidad").keyup(function () {
    searchHelpers.forEach(element => {
      document.getElementById('wrapper').removeChild(element);
    })
    searchHelpers = [];

    var texto = $("#buscar_unidad").val().toUpperCase();
    if (texto.length !== 0) {
      $("#nu0").children("li").each(function (i, e) {
        ul = $(e).children("ul");
        ul.children("li").each(function (ii, ee) {

          var search = $(ee).children("a").html().toUpperCase();
          var resultado = search.indexOf(texto);
          if (texto.length > 1 && resultado !== -1) {
            $(ee).children("a").css("color", "#00ff00");

            let containerDistance = $("#nu0").position().top;
            let marker = document.createElement('div');
            marker.classList.add('bar-marker');
            marker.style.top = `${(($(ee).position().top - containerDistance) * 100) / $("#nu0")[0].scrollHeight }%`;
            marker.style.width = `${getScrollBarWidth()}px`;


            document.getElementById("nu0").appendChild(marker);
            $("#wrapper").append(marker);
            
            searchHelpers.push(marker);
          } else {
            $("#nu0").offset()
            $(ee).children("a").css("color", "");
          }
        });
        
        
      });
    } else {
      $("#nu0").children("li").each(function (i, e) {
        ul = $(e).children("ul");
        ul.children("li").each(function (ii, ee) {
          $(ee).children("a").css("color", "");
        });

      });
    }


  });
});
```

```css
.bar-marker {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffbb01;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

#nu0 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.spacer {
  height: 6000px;
}

#tester {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="buscar">Buscar</label> <input id="buscar_unidad" type="text" />
    <div id="wrapper">
      <ul id="nu0">
        <li>
          Distrito
          <ul id="nu1">
            <li>
              <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/2"
                >DIRECCION EJECUTIVA</a
              >
              <ul id="nu2"></ul>
            </li>
  
            <li>
              <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/3"
                >UNIDAD DE MANTENIMIENTO Y COORDINACION</a
              >
              <ul id="nu3"></ul>
            </li>
  
            <li>
              <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/4"
                >UNIDAD DE SEGUIMIENTO A PROYECTOS</a
              >
              <ul id="nu4"></ul>
            </li>
  
            <li>
              <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/5"
                >UNIDAD DE ESTUDIOS Y ELABORACION DE PROYECTOS</a
              >
              <ul id="nu5"></ul>
            </li>
  
            <li>
              <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/8"
                >UNIDAD ADMINISTRATIVA Y FINANCIERA</a
              >
              <ul id="nu8"></ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li1">
              <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="1" style="color: red">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
  
        <li>
          Maestranza
          <ul id="nu6">
            <li>
              <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/7"
                >UNIDAD DE MANTENIMIENTO DE EQUIPOS</a
              >
              <ul id="nu7"></ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li6">
              <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="6" style="color: red">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
  
        <li>
          RESIDENCIA ACASIO
          <ul id="nu9">
            <li>
              <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/15"
                >RESIDENCIA ACASIO</a
              >
              <ul id="nu15"></ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li9">
              <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="9" style="color: red">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva de algo, o cuando menos que te dé una idea de como hacerlo :)

Comment: Mil gracias por la ayuda ahora no se que respuesta aceptar.

Answer (score 2):

Para pintar la sección en los textos que coinciden con la cadena puedes tener una clase para pintarlas:

```
.pintar{
      color: #00ff00; 
 }
```

Luego dividir cada cadena por el texto con `split(texto)` de modo que si el resultado (un array) tiene tamaño > 1, el texto que contiene la cadena.

```
var resultado=search.split(texto);
```

Luego unes el *array* reemplazando la cadena por la misma dentro de un `<span>` con la clase `pintar`:

```
resultado.join(`<span class="pintar">${texto}</span>`)
```

Luego para eliminar todos los `<span>` puedes tener una función `limpiar()` que se ejecute al inicio de la función.

Puede que tengas elementos HTML dentro de los `<a>` en lugar de texto (como iconos `<i>`), en ese caso puedes evitar que se aplique el cambio con:

```
search.indexOf('<')<0
```

El código queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#buscar_unidad").keyup(function(){
    var texto=$("#buscar_unidad").val().toUpperCase();
    limpiar();
    if(texto.length!==0)
      $("#nu0").children("li").each(function(i,e){
        ul=$(e).children("ul");
        ul.children("li").each(function(ii,ee){
          var search=$(ee).children("a").html().toUpperCase();
          var resultado=search.split(texto);
          if(resultado.length > 1 && search.indexOf('<')<0)
            $(ee).children("a").html(resultado.join(`<span class="pintar">${texto}</span>`));
        });
      });  
  });
});

function limpiar(){
  $("#nu0").children("li").each(function(i,e){
    ul=$(e).children("ul");
    ul.children("li").each(function(ii,ee){
      var search=$(ee).children("a").html();
      search=search.split('<span class="pintar">').join('');
      search=search.split('</span>').join('');
      $(ee).children("a").html(search);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.pintar{
      color: #00ff00; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="buscar">Buscar</label> <input id="buscar_unidad" type="text">
<ul id="nu0">
    <li>
        Distrito
        <ul id="nu1">
            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/2">DIRECCION EJECUTIVA</a>
                <ul id="nu2">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/3">UNIDAD DE MANTENIMIENTO Y  COORDINACION</a>
                <ul id="nu3">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/4">UNIDAD DE SEGUIMIENTO  A PROYECTOS</a>
                <ul id="nu4">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/5">UNIDAD DE ESTUDIOS Y ELABORACION  DE PROYECTOS</a>
                <ul id="nu5">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/8">UNIDAD  ADMINISTRATIVA Y FINANCIERA</a>
                <ul id="nu8">
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li1">
                <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="1" style="color: red">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        Maestranza
        <ul id="nu6">
            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/7">UNIDAD DE MANTENIMIENTO  DE EQUIPOS</a>
                <ul id="nu7">
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li6">
                <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="6" style="color: red">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        RESIDENCIA ACASIO
        <ul id="nu9">
            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/15">RESIDENCIA ACASIO</a>
                <ul id="nu15">
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li9">
                <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="9" style="color: red">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Otra opción es emplear la librería [**azlejs**](https://azlejs.com/) la cual ofrece gran cantidad de funciones css para dar estilo a los elementos de una pagina de forma mas simple.

Luego agregando el aporte de Daniel Rodríguez Meza ya tienes el resultado que esperas en el siguiente código:

```js
function getScrollBarWidth() {
  var inner = document.createElement('p');
  inner.style.width = "100%";
  inner.style.height = "200px";

  var outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.position = "absolute";
  outer.style.top = "0px";
  outer.style.left = "0px";
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  outer.style.width = "200px";
  outer.style.height = "150px";
  outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
  outer.appendChild(inner);

  document.body.appendChild(outer);
  var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
  var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
  if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

  document.body.removeChild(outer);

  return (w1 - w2);
};

let searchHelpers = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#buscar_unidad").keyup(function () {
    limpiar();
    var texto = $("#buscar_unidad").val().toUpperCase();
    if (texto.length !== 0) {
      $("#nu0").children("li").each(function (i, e) {
        ul = $(e).children("ul");
        ul.children("li").each(function (ii, ee) {

          var search = $(ee).children("a").html().toUpperCase();
          var resultado=search.split(texto);
          if(resultado.length > 1 && search.indexOf('<')<0){
            $(ee).children("a").html(resultado.join(`<span class="pintar">${texto}</span>`));

            let containerDistance = $("#nu0").position().top;
            let marker = document.createElement('div');
            marker.classList.add('bar-marker');
            marker.style.top = `${(($(ee).position().top - 7  - containerDistance) * 100) / $("#nu0")[0].scrollHeight }%`;
            marker.style.width = `${getScrollBarWidth()}px`;
            document.getElementById("nu0").appendChild(marker);
            $("#wrapper").append(marker);
            searchHelpers.push(marker);
          } else 
            $("#nu0").offset()
        });
      });
    } 
  });
});

function limpiar(){
  searchHelpers.forEach(element => 
    document.getElementById('wrapper').removeChild(element))
  searchHelpers = [];
  $("#nu0").children("li").each(function(i,e){
    ul=$(e).children("ul");
    ul.children("li").each(function(ii,ee){
      var search=$(ee).children("a").html();
      search=search.split('<span class="pintar">').join('');
      search=search.split('</span>').join('');
      $(ee).children("a").html(search);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.pintar{
      color: #00ff00; 
  }
  .bar-marker {
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    right: 0;
    background: #ffbb01;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
  }

  #nu0 {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  #wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }

  .spacer {
    height: 6000px;
  }

  #tester {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
```

```html
<label for="buscar">Buscar</label> <input id="buscar_unidad" type="text">
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="nu0">
    <li>
        Distrito
        <ul id="nu1">
            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/2">DIRECCION EJECUTIVA</a>
                <ul id="nu2">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/3">UNIDAD DE MANTENIMIENTO Y  COORDINACION</a>
                <ul id="nu3">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/4">UNIDAD DE SEGUIMIENTO  A PROYECTOS</a>
                <ul id="nu4">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/5">UNIDAD DE ESTUDIOS Y ELABORACION  DE PROYECTOS</a>
                <ul id="nu5">
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/8">UNIDAD  ADMINISTRATIVA Y FINANCIERA</a>
                <ul id="nu8">
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li1">
                <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="1" style="color: red">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        Maestranza
        <ul id="nu6">
            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/7">UNIDAD DE MANTENIMIENTO  DE EQUIPOS</a>
                <ul id="nu7">
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li6">
                <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="6" style="color: red">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        RESIDENCIA ACASIO
        <ul id="nu9">
            <li>
                <a class="name" href="http://localhost/public/planta/15">RESIDENCIA ACASIO</a>
                <ul id="nu15">
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="li9">
                <a href="#" onclick="nu(this)" data-i="9" style="color: red">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

De esa forma el buscador ya es como el de google chrome, saludos.

Comment: Mil gracias por la ayuda, no sabes cuanto me ayudo todo, la verdad ahora no se que respuesta aceptar.

Comment: @Shassain no tengo problema con que aceptes la otra respuesta, adelante.